# Iterate through file.txt and update map values

Tags: c++

Im trying to update my map as i iterate though my file.txt 
I added some "test code" to output my values and im getting 125.00 (which is what i want) and 100 (which i dont want)

I dont think that im inserting it into the map the right way or retrieving it the right way. Because the value before i add it is right and when i retrieve it, its not the right way

```
if (accountFile.is_open())
    {
        while (!accountFile.eof())
        {
            (std::getline(accountFile, accounttemp.user, ',') &&
                std::getline(accountFile, accounttemp.trantype, ',') &&
                std::getline(accountFile, (accounttemp.bal)));

            (std::getline(loginFile, logintemp.user, ',') &&
             std::getline(loginFile, (logintemp.pass)));
            cout << logintemp.user << endl;

            //http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/
            // find value given key
            it = balances.find(accounttemp.user);
            if (it != balances.end())
            {
                double holder = 0;
                if (accounttemp.trantype == "D")
                {
                    holder = std::stod(accounttemp.bal) + std::stod(balances.find(accounttemp.user)->second);
                }
                if (accounttemp.trantype == "W")
                {
                    holder = std::stod(accounttemp.bal) - std::stod(balances.find(accounttemp.user)->second);
                }
                stringstream stream;
                stream << fixed << setprecision(2) << holder;
                string s = stream.str();
                accounttemp.bal = s;

                //this is were i added some test code to see my output
                cout << accounttemp.bal << endl;                    
                balances.insert(pair<string, string>(accounttemp.user, accounttemp.bal));
                cout << (balances.find(accounttemp.user)->second) << endl;
enter code here
                //out put is 125.00 
                //out put is 100
            }
            else
            {
                balances.insert(std::pair<string, string>(accounttemp.user, (accounttemp.bal)));
            }



        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
        it = balances.find(accounttemp.user);
        if (it != balances.end())
        {
```

Which enters the block only if `balances` contains an `accounttemp.user` element. Then the code has:

```
            balances.insert(pair<string, string>(accounttemp.user, accounttemp.bal));
```

which does nothing, since the map already contains an element with that key. Note that `insert` does not replace an existing element. At most, for `std::multimap` a new element, with the same key, might be inserted. But with `std::map` nothing will happen at all. Look at the [documentation of `std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

> Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place.

I assume it returned `false` for you, since no insertion took place.

FIX: update the iterator instead:

```
            // instead of:
            // balances.insert(pair<string, string>(accounttemp.user, accounttemp.bal));
            it->second = accountemp.bal;
```

Comment: Thanks this seems like it works for me `it->second = accountemp.bal;`